# IP, MIP and MIP* with super-polynomial verifier

Tags: complexity-classes, interactive-proofs

Regarding each of the above classes, what are the currently known upper bounds when the verifier is given more than polynomial power?

Specifically, when do we reach ALL in each of the above classes with respect to (as a function of) the power of the verifier?

Comment: If we allowed sending superpolynomial bits, the extension of IP will be superpolynomial space and the extension of MIP will be $NPTIME(2^{superpoly(n)})$.

Comment: @MohsenGhorbani - You mean NTIME(2^{superpoly(n)}) right?

Comment: Of course, it was my mistake.